# jQuery how to read and format data for autocomplete using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have tried to implement a simple autocomplete using jQuery. But as it turns out, it is not that simple for me.
I have an `<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />` and I try to make it autocomplete.

I want to read my database with a PHP script that returns the data in JSON (or whatever you recommend). The data is supposed to be a list of words, nothing complicated (["abc","bcd","cde"]); no additional categories or things.

To do so I read the API [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), but I am not too familiar with anonymous functions in JS and things.

What I tried so far:

```
$(function() {
  function response(){};
  $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response(data)){ajaxRequest(request, response)}
    });
});
```

But this does not work I fear. Also I totally do not know in what format ajaxRequest() has to return the data.

Is somebody out there who got the geniality to know this and can help me?
I would be very glad!

Thanks a lot!
-Yatekii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the data to the response callback

```
    $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            $.getJSON( "url.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                response( data );
            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: Ok I might seem retarded now, but I still do not get it ..

[JS](http://pastebin.com/W5sF9qxR)

The code of get_data.php looks like this:

[PHP](http://pastebin.com/YzsyDDqP)

What the hell am I doing wrong? I do not get an error nor does something change.

Comment: have you checked what your php file is returning? Anyway, set 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
at the top of your php file, you never know...

Comment: Yeah it is returning this format: ['x','y','z'] .. and nope, no errors .. if you want to check it out: [poe.wapple.ch](http://poe.wapple.ch) is the url .. the first field (character) should have the autocomplete attached to it ..

Comment: JSON needs to have double-quotes, not single quotes. correct format: ["x","y","z"]

Comment: Yep and I had a mistake in my function .. Thanks a lot guys!